# mysql, trigger on insert to limit the number of expired passwords stored

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am requiring that the user's current password cannot match the last five used passwords. The expired passwords  will be stored in a table similar to this.

```
################################################################
#                             table_A                          #
################################################################
# id #     label    # attr_string #    attr_datetime    # u_id #
################################################################
#  1 # expired_pass #  some_hash  # YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS #  1   #
#  2 # expired_pass #  some_hash  # YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS #  1   #
#  3 # expired_pass #  some_hash  # YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS #  1   #
#  4 # expired_pass #  some_hash  # YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS #  1   #
#  5 # expired_pass #  some_hash  # YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS #  1   #
################################################################
```

Now I am wanting a trigger that upon input checks if there are >= 5 expired passwords already stored if so then remove the oldest password. This is what I have come up with so far.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER removePass AFTER INSERT ON `user_attributes`(
        SET @user_id := SELECT u_id FROM `user_attributes` WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()//
        SET @num := SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `user_attributes` WHERE u_id = @user_id AND label = 'expired_password'//
        IF @num >= 5 THEN
            DELETE FROM `user_attributes`
            WHERE id IN(
                SELECT id
                FROM `user_attributes`
                WHERE u_id = @user_id
                AND label = 'expired_pass'
                ORDER BY attr_datetime DESC
                LIMIT 1

            )
        END IF
    )//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why use `attr_datetime` if you have `id`s? maybe do something like `WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM user_attributes WHERE u_id = @user_id AND label= 'expired_pass'`? Also having `DESC` in the `ORDER BY` clause will delete the newest password, won't it?

Comment: I hadn't thought about using the id in that manner. Thanks that solves my issues.

Comment: `MIN(id)` is probably more correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid using `attr_datetime` and rely on `id`s:

```
DELETE FROM `user_attributes`
            WHERE id = (
                SELECT MIN(id)
                FROM `user_attributes`
                WHERE u_id = @user_id
                AND label = 'expired_pass'
            )
```

P.S. Thank to @sixlettervariables for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642670/mysql-trigger-on-insert-to-limit-the-number-of-expired-passwords-stored#comment13799473_10642670) and Brock for [advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132870/question-deleted-by-the-poster-because-the-issue-is-resolved#comment368166_132870).